# How to add text on the top of bar chart in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, data-visualization, bar-chart

I have built a bar chart and now I have a very specific need. I want to add `diff` and `perdiff` values on on the top of bars, but could not find any suitable way for that.
Also, I want to show x-scale without breaks, like 0, 25,50,100,125....

```
df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","USA","USA"),
                  Year = c("2021", "2022","2021","2022"),
                  Sales = c(103, 192, 144, 210),
                  diff = c(89, " ",66," "),
                  perdiff = c(86.4, " ",45.83," "))



ggplot(df, aes(fill=Year, y=Origin, x=Sales)) + 
    geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")
```

Desired outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column `label` was added for labeling on the plot.
BTW, the label of your desired outcome is switched. (According to your `df`, 89, 46.4 for Canada).

```r
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame (Origin = c("Canada", "Canada","USA","USA"),
                  Year = c("2021", "2022","2021","2022"),
                  Sales = c(103, 192, 144, 210),
                  diff = c(89, " ",66," "),
                  perdiff = c(86.4, " ",45.83," "))


df <- df %>% mutate(label= ifelse(diff!=" ",paste0(diff,", ",perdiff,'%'),NA))
ggplot(df, aes(fill=Year, y=Origin, x=Sales)) + 
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label=label, x=200), fontface='bold') +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,200,25))+
  theme()
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>